# OSRM HTTP Queries

Tags: openstreetmap

I was checking out the a way that I could query OSM using HTTP requests and I found this [link](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/1968) where the guy uses this to query OSRM:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=49.1716783,-0.34655726&loc=49.17131276,-0.34673758
```

Now when I try this it gives the following error:

```
The OSRM Demo server has moved to API Version 5. 
Documentation for the new version can be found at
https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md
```

I went there and tried to form my own query using the new rules:

```
http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/car/{19.411989},{-99.164623}[;{19.412344},{-99.162805}
```

And it does not work either. So my question is am I using this thing right? I am just discovering the service, and heard some people install OSRM servers. I don't really want to install anything just find a way to build HTTP requests, if possible of course.

Comment: OSRM has a good [documentation](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.7.0/api/) with lots of examples. Did you read it? Also note that the public OSRM server currently has some issues that will hopefully get fixed soon (see https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/4101 and https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/4100).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get rid of the curly braces in the request and the location should be in lon1,lat1;lon2,lat2 fashion. i.e.,
http://router.project-osrm.org/trip/v1/driving/19.411989,-89.164623;19.412344,-89.162805?overview=false

Comment: I send it, and I got response. How I can to get points array or poliline object from this response?